# Set sorting for Survey Response by Default

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, survey, survey-list, sorting

I'm trying to set the default sort on responses from a Survey List to descending however I don't see where I can do this or even modify the view.  Is there some where I can set the sort on the Survey Response view?

Comment: Which view are you using? "All responses" or "Overview"?

Comment: All Responses view

Comment: I am not sure if there is permanent way to set it in default list view. But you can sort using URL something like: `<siteUrl>/Lists/<listName>/AllItems.aspx#InplviewHash043e3679-4e4a-47d4-896b-4042997f2d41=SortField%3DModified-SortDir%3DDesc`.

Comment: Is there a way to modify the All Response view?  I've tried looking at the settings and I can't find any way of doing that.

Comment: I was able to get the result I needed for the project.  I posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a co worker showed me how to do this:

1. Go to the All Response View.
2. Then Edit the Page.
3. Then Edit the Web Part
4. Below the "Select View" drop down, click on the "Edit the Current View"
5. There you can do the standard View modification(s).